# building cmake from source for Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I get the following error, if trying to build cmake 3.18 from https://github.com/microsoft/CMake.

```
gmake: *** No rule to make target '/home/ubuntu/Projects/CMake/Source/cmStringTable.cxx'
```

The file by the way is not in any of the folders.

The system is ubuntu arm64.

It is said that this version must be used because of the activated CMake Server mode.

I can build cmake from kitware on the same machine without problems.

Comment: I see no `cmStringTable.cxx` string in the [Source/CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/microsoft/CMake/blob/v3.18-MSVC/Source/CMakeLists.txt). Probably, you have this file corrupted?

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with Mircosoft's fork: https://github.com/microsoft/CMake/issues/90

User "tinco" writes:

> I fixed it for myself by not using bootstrap and instead using cmake to compile itself.
>
> I think the fix for this is to remove mention of cmStringTable from the bootstrap script. A more complete fix would be to have the bootstrap script generate the components instead of having them hardcoded.

So you should use your system CMake to build Microsoft's fork instead of using their bootstrap script.

---

> It is said that this version must be used because of the activated CMake Server mode.

I wonder, though, *who* says this? The CMake Server mode was deprecated a while ago. Microsoft releases its own binaries as part of Visual Studio 2019's CMake tools for Windows. I am curious why you want to use this fork on Linux, rather than the upstream version.

Comment: Thanks, you mean I can use CMake from Kitware without problems? I have not the time to make a diff.